# EmberJS - promise returned by transitionToRoute is not resolved when the transition is aborted and retried

Tags: ember.js, promise

I have an action in `PostController` which has the following code.

```
var self = this;
this.transitionToRoute('post').promise.then(function(){
  self.set('isEditing', true);
});
```

But, inside the `PostRoute`'s `willTransition` action I have a logic to check for `dirtyComment` and abort the transition and ask for user confirmation, and depending on the user input, will retry the transition or leave the transition as aborted and do nothing. I need this logic to reside in `willTransition` of `PostRoute` because, this check needs to be performed whenever a user tries to transition out of the `/post` route.

```
willTransition: function(transition) {
  if (this.controller.get('isCommentDirty')){
    transition.abort();
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to abort the comment?")) {
      // If the user confirms perform some logic
      transition.retry();
    }
  } else{
    // Bubble the `willTransition` action so that
    // parent routes can decide whether or not to abort.
    return true;
  }
}
```

Now, when the comment is dirty and the transition is aborted and retried, the promise is not full filled. I know this happens because `retry` creates a completely new `Transition` object. But, is there a workaround for this?

Also, what I do not understand is if ember should actually deal with this?

Comment: Possible revenant discussion: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5064

Answer (score 0):

I resolve similar situation (auth checking) using an another one promise, which I've fully control. It's not your case though.

You can invert the behavior by ether creating post.edit route or moving conformation logic to the controller (not route) like this:

In PostController:

```
var self = this,
    isCommentDirty = this.get('isCommentDirty');

if (isCommentDirty && confirm("Are you sure you want to abort the comment?")) {
  this.transitionToRoute('post').then(function(){
    self.set('isEditing', true);
  });
}
```

or

```
var self = this,
    isCommentDirty = this.get('isCommentDirty');

if (isCommentDirty && confirm("Are you sure you want to abort the comment?")) {
  this.set('isEditing', true);
  this.transitionToRoute('post');
}
```

By the way. If you want to restrict an editing of dirty comments, you can hide 'edit' button in a template. For that case, with 'post.edit' route, code in PostController would be:

```
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to abort the comment?")) {
  this.transitionToRoute('post.edit');
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer @Microfed. Sorry I was not clear about this in my question, I have the logic to check for dirty comment in `willTransition` of `PostRoute` because, I want this check to happen whenever a user tries to move out of `/post`. Your solution needs to be implemented in all routes.